# sumar filas , columnas y diagnoales

Tags: c#

debo hacer un cuadro magico, ya tengo la matriz y leo los valores que en ella hay, posteriormente deseo primero sumar las filas, pero no se como hacer para que automaticamente las posiciones 0.0,0,1,0,2 etc etc, tengo la parte final del codigo asi

```
Console.WriteLine("suma filas");
            for (i = 0; i < matriz.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < matriz.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    if (i>sumafilas)
                    {
                        sumafilas += matriz[i, i];
                    }


                }

                Console.Write(sumafilas);
                Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: Hola jorge, tu código no esta completo, tu pregunta no se entiende. Por favor mejora la redacción de tu pregunta

Comment: Cuando hago la pregunta y le doy enter no hace el salto de linea sino que inmediatemente guarda la pregunta , o en este caso el comentario

Comment: Debes [edit] tu pregunta con mas detalles. Esta poca información **no es suficiente**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar las sumas de un cuadro mágico mediante ciclos:

```
int [, ] mn = new int [3, 3] {{4,9,2}, {3,5,7}, {8,1,6}};

        //SUMA DE LINEAS
        for (int i = 0; i < mn.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            int suma = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < mn.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                suma += mn[i, j];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Linea " + i + " = " + suma);
        }
        //SUMA DE COLUMNAS

        for (int j = 0; j < mn.GetLength(0); j++)
        {
            int suma = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < mn.GetLength(1); i++)
            {
                suma += mn[i, j];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Columna " + j + " = " + suma);
        }
        //SUMA DE DIAGONAL \
        int sumad1 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mn.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = i; j <= i; j++)
            {
                sumad1 += mn[i, j];
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Linea diagonal \\ = " + sumad1);
        //SUMA DE DIAGONAL /
        int sumad2 = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < mn.GetLength(0); j++)
        {
            for (int i = mn.GetLength(0) -j - 1; i == mn.GetLength(0) -j - 1 ; i++)
            {
                sumad2 += mn[i, j];
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Linea diagonal / = " + sumad2);
```

Saludos.